# How to insert image from link in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, images, buttons

In the TinyMCE editor that comes with WordPress there is no button to insert image from link. I know that you can do this using the upload/insert section. But let us say that I don't want to allow users to upload images but want them to be able to insert images by linking them. If I remove the upload capabilities, the upload/insert section disappears altogether.
Is there already a method to do this on WordPress?

Comment: hot linking which is what u will be doing is not always liked by other sites. plus they will cause a huge drag on speed and can hurt your ranking in search engine

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But is it not okay to link to images on sites such as Picasa? Because that's what I was planning to do.

Comment: photobucket, ImageShack, picsa etc. pretty much any image hosting site is fine but some have bandwidth limits the one you want I believe does not. I know that a lot of other sites don't like it when someone uses there images without permission because you cause there bandwidth to go up. but as Picasa is owned by Google you should not have an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TinyMCE Advanced](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) allows you to add several buttons including images.

Answer (score 0):

here is a link on the code page. I can't write the code for some reason my browser is not accepting the code tags will try another computer when possible but the link explains all. here is the link.  http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons